# Airtel 4G dongle mounting

Tags: filesystems, mount, lte, huawei

I am using a HUAWEI mobile broadband LTE USB stick model E3272.

Whenever I insert it, it displays an error message like:

```
Error mounting /dev/sr1 at /media/bhuvan/airtel:
Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sr1" "/media/bhuvan/airtel"' exited with non-zero exit status 32:
mount: block device /dev/sr1 is write-protected, mounting read-only mount: special device /dev/sr1 does not exist.
```

In Windows there is no such problem.

I am using kernel version "3.16.0-46-generic" on 14.04.1-Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore that.

Many mobile modems these days present themselves as a USB stick until they notice they're being used as a modem. The idea is that the USB stick contains the drivers; without them the device can't function, so as long as the modem isn't being used the drivers haven't been installed yet so the USB stick thing stays there. Once the host is using those drivers, the device knows that the driver install files are no longer needed, and the modem disables that functionality.

When you plug it in, the system sees the filesystem on the USB stick thing, and tries to mount it. At the same time, some other part of the system sees the modem, and starts talking to it, so the filesystem disappears. The filesystem operation is then only halfway through finishing, so you get an error message about that. But it's harmless.